# how to list out international-phone-number in Angular Material V6?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular5, angular-material2

I am working on an application that uses Angular Material V6. I want to list out the international phone number with flags in Material component text box. I searched the Internet and found an npm module but it was using bootstrap text component. I added a screenshot taking a look at it. Bootstrap differs from angular material text box component.

Now it is:

[image]

Angular material component:

[image]

Sample code:

```
<mat-form-field color="warn" class="form-field-width">
 <int-phone-prefix matInput [locale]="'es'"></int-phone-prefix>
</mat-form-field>
```

ERROR:

> ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.

please give me your suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the documentation
Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl
This error occurs when you have not added a form field control to your form field. If your form field contains a native <input> or <textarea> element, make sure you've added the matInput directive to it and have imported MatInputModule. Other components that can act as a form field control include <mat-select>, <mat-chip-list>, and any custom form field controls you've created

Comment: yeah, Mat form field must contain mat input field. you are right. then how do i list out the international phone numbers? give me your idea please.

Comment: Could you tell what library do you use for international phone prefix? I'm working in Angular 6. Some advice?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working with different dependency, it's [ng2-tel-input](https://github.com/gauravsoni119/ng2-tel-input). Sample source code (on top of this remember to follow the "Installation" available in the repo):

**contact.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <input 
    matInput 
    ng2TelInput 
    [ng2TelInputOptions]="{initialCountry: 'us'}"
    formControlName="formControlPhone" 
    (hasError)="hasError($event)" />
  <mat-error
    *ngIf="
    !contactForm.get('formControlPhone').valid &&
    contactForm.get('formControlPhone').touched
    "
  >This is an <strong>invalid</strong> phone number.
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

**contact.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatInputModule
} from '@angular/material';
import {Ng2TelInputModule} from 'ng2-tel-input';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ContactComponent],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    Ng2TelInputModule
  ],
})
export class ContactModule {}
```

**contact.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.scss']
})
export class ContactComponent {
  public contactForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.contactForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      formControlPhone: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
  hasError(event: any): void {
    if (!event && this.contactForm.value.formControlPhone !== '') {
      this.contactForm.get('formControlPhone').setErrors(['invalid_cell_phone', true]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me but I'm able to retrieve only the phone number, not the code. Any solution?

Comment: @StevenHenry retrieving a prefix is on my TODO list still.

Answer (score 0):

check if you have imported matinput module

```
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
  ...
    MatInputModule
  ...

]
```

You can also refer the link 
https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7898

this type of error is described in documentation, please refer that also

Comment: yeah, Mat form field must contain mat input field. you are right. then how do i list out the international phone numbers? give me your idea please.

Comment: https://github.com/hodgepodgers/ng-intl-tel-input
check the link,  it may help you

Comment: this will also help you, https://www.npmjs.com/package/international-phone-number

Comment: yes, the links which you have given is in angular 1. but i am working in angular 5

Comment: yeah i used this same npm module. but can not add this line
<int-phone-prefix [(ngModel)]="phoneNumber"></int-phone-prefix>
this is not an angular material io component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172467/discussion-between-navaneethan-arun-and-akhil-aravind).